# LEFT JOIN returns null

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have following `2 tables`, `users` and `userRoles` with following `records` in it:

```
userId  userName  firstName  lastName  password  image userRoles_roleId
........................................................................
1       a@a.dk    A          A         1                1
2       b@b.dk    B          B         2                2


roleId  userRole
.................
1       admin
2       user
```

With the following query this is what I get:

```
SELECT users.userId, users.userName, users.firstName
     , users.lastName, users.password, users.image
     , userRoles.userRole FROM users 
LEFT JOIN userRoles ON users.userID = userRoles.roleId;

userId  userName  firstName  lastName  password image  userRole
................................................................
1       a@a.dk    A          A            1            NULL
2       b@b.d     B          B            2            NULL
```

Of course what I would like to get is `admin` and `user`.

Am I am not understanding well what `LEFT JOIN` it supposed to do or what´s wrong?

Comment: problem statement is not clear

Comment: Should show something with the data you're showing us, but your query doesn't look right. Something tells me you want to use `users.userRoles_roleId` for the join rather than `users.userID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `left [outer] join` will permit a row from the "right" table to be displayed even if there is no matching row in the "left" table. However if you don't choose the correct columns for the join then you won't get good results. In the `users` table there is a `foreign key` column and the name of that column indicates which table it relates to. That column is `userRoles_roleId` so you need to change the query to this:

```
SELECT users.userId, users.userName, users.firstName
     , users.lastName, users.password, users.image
     , userRoles.userRole 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN userRoles ON users.userRoles_roleId = userRoles.roleId;
```